# Doesn't support angular-ru/ngxs with Angular v16

Tags: angular, typescript, ngxs

I installed angular-ru/ngxs. but I cannot import any thing from package, it shows "Cannot find module '@angular-ru/ngxs' or its corresponding type declarations."

[image]

[image]

this is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "state-management-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-ru/ngxs": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.0",
    "@ngxs/logger-plugin": "^3.8.1-dev.master-9ffd0c4",
    "@ngxs/store": "^3.8.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: That package appears to be [stuck at Angular v13](https://github.com/Angular-RU/angular-ru-sdk/blob/master/package.json). It would not surprise me if it did not work with TypeScript > 4.6...

Comment: It's likely you didn't install that package.